# Can't find "Generate Signed APK/Bundle" in Build menu

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, build, apk

Some options are missing in the Build menu. I couldn't understand why. I couldn't figure out what I did. Should I add a module? I was not sure if I did something missing while creating the project.

[image]

Comment: File->Invalidate caches/Restart

Comment: Past the minimal code and error message instead of a screenshot would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

read the flutter Doc maybe it can help:
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

will I understood from the doc that you need to take your Keystore and run the command but I don't know where till now, but after u take your Keystore password and those things you will need to create /android/key.properties in your project, and I think that flutter is the cause of this because I opened a kotlin project and the menu was full